# Select random item from array

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a game for my two girls. It randomly selects an adjective and a noun, then displays the words for them to act out.

I can get the random words to print to the console, but now I need them to appear in the html.

```
Array.prototype.sample = function(){
  return this[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length)];
}


var randomAdj = (["happy", "sad", "bouncy", "silly"].sample());
var randNoun = (["monkey", "butterfly", "puppy"].sample());

document.getElementById(#adj).textContent = randomAdj;
document.getElementById(#noun).textContent = randomNoun;
```

The last two lines aren't working for me (`#adj` and `#noun` are span ids used in the html).

I am only a couple of weeks into learning, so I might be missing something super obvious here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The random part should work (keep in mind that modifying the prototypes is not a good practice, tho), but you have two syntax errors:

```
document.getElementById(#adj).textContent = randomAdj;
document.getElementById(#noun).textContent = randomNoun;
```

Pass `"adj"` and `"noun"` as strings:

```
document.getElementById("adj").textContent = randomAdj;
document.getElementById("noun").textContent = randomNoun;
```

You don't need the `#` snippet in the `getElementById` call.
Also note that you you are using `randomNoun` but you declared `randNoun`. Here is the working code and example:

```js
function randomItem(arr){
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
}


var randomAdj = randomItem(["happy", "sad", "bouncy", "silly"]);
var randomNoun = randomItem(["monkey", "butterfly", "puppy"]);

document.getElementById("adj").textContent = randomAdj;
document.getElementById("noun").textContent = randomNoun;
```

```html
<span id="adj"></span>
<span id="noun"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was something little and dumb

Comment: @kristijoy81 You're welcome! Don't forget to check the answer using the `✔` button in the left side of my answer (under the vote section). Hope your girls will have fun playing it. :)

Answer (score 0):

worng

```
document.getElementById(#adj).textContent = randomAdj;
document.getElementById(#noun).textContent = randomNoun;
```

use

```
document.getElementById("adj").innerHTML = randomAdj;
document.getElementById("noun").innerHTML = randomNoun;
```